# Exceeding the monster limit due to an encounter

Tags: arkham-horror

In the "The King in Yellow" expansion, there is an encounter card for the library that results in all monsters of a certain type, including those in the outskirts, relocating to the investigators location. The card then states that you 'must immediately evade or defeat them'.

If the investigator succesfully evades them all or gets reduced to 0 stamina/sanity, do the monsters all remain in that location even though the monster limit is most likely exceeded?

Comment: What is the card's name?

Comment: @Ramiro the card doesn't have a name - it is just an encounter card from the yellow deck (Miskatonic University District)

Comment: Of course. Sorry for the dumb question. I simply wanted to get an easier reference for the full card text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know there is a card listed in the FAQ that does exactly this but in the graveyard, I don't remember one from the library, but the ruling would be transferable.

From the [Arkham Horror FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf)

> Q: A Graveyard encounter summons "all Undead monsters in Arkham, the Outskirts, and the Sky" to the Graveyard. If this would bring the number of monsters in Arkham above the monster limit, which ones are sent to the Outskirts?
>
> A: Any monsters that were in the Outskirts when this encounter was drawn are the first to be returned to the Outskirts if the monster limit is exceeded. In the event that not all monsters that came from the Outskirts need to be returned there, the first player decides which monster tokens are placed back in the Outskirts. If more monsters still need to be moved to the Outskirts, move the monsters that came from other towns (Dunwich, Kingsport, or  Innsmouth) to the Outskirts until the number of monsters in Arkham is again at the monster limit. In the event that not all monsters that came from another town need to be returned there, the first player decides which of those monster tokens are moved to the Outskirts.

Comment: So, after the evade/combat checks are all resolved, I would need to bring the monsters back down to the monster limit?

Comment: Yes. These cards allow you to break the monster limit, but only for the duration of the card's effect. As soon as you have resolved the card the monster limit must then be re-established.